# How to redirect a push notification when the app is killed/background to a content page to display the notification message

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification

when I tap my received notification while app is running in the foreground my code works fine and direct me to the desired content page with the notification message but while app is in background or killed tapping the notification starts the application and does not redirect me to the desired content page

i would appreciate the Help so thx in advance :)

here is my code

splashactivity.cs

```
 [Activity(Label = "myapp", Icon = "@drawable/qt" ,Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash",LaunchMode=LaunchMode.SingleTop, MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ConfigurationChanges =ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class splashactivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {        
        internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);            
            string message = Intent.GetStringExtra("message");
            if (message == null)
            {
                LoadApplication(new App(false));
            }
            else
            {
                App.message = message;
              
                LoadApplication(new App(true));
            }
            IsPlayServicesAvailable();
            CreateNotificationChannel();    
        }
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.cs

```
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
      public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(message);
            string messageBody = string.Empty;

            if (message.GetNotification() != null)
            {
                messageBody = message.GetNotification().Body;

            }           
            else
            {
                messageBody = message.Data.Values.First();
            }            
            SendLocalNotification(messageBody);
            SendMessageToMainPage(messageBody);
        }
  void SendLocalNotification(string body)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            intent.PutExtra("message", body);

            //Unique request code to avoid PendingIntent collision.
            var requestCode = new Random().Next();
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
            
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle textStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            textStyle.BigText(body);

            // Create the notification and publish it ...
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.NotificationChannelName)
                .SetContentTitle("myapp")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.NQ3)
                .SetContentText(body)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetShowWhen(false)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent).SetStyle(textStyle);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                notificationBuilder.SetChannelId(Constants.NotificationChannelName);
            }

            var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());           
        }

        void SendMessageToMainPage(string body)
        {
            (App.Current.MainPage as DOTFORMS3.Views.MSG)?.AddMessage(body);

        }
    }
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "myapp", Icon = "@drawable/qt", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {              
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);           
           

            IsPlayServicesAvailable();
            CreateNotificationChannel(); 
            string message = Intent.GetStringExtra("message");
            if (message == null)
            {
                LoadApplication(new App(false));
            }
            else
            {
                App.message = message;

                LoadApplication(new App(true));
            }
        }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {        
        public static string message;
        public App(bool b)
        {
            if (b)
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DOTFORMS3.Views.MSG(message));
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DOTFORMS3.Page2());
            }
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
```

My payload used is from azure notification hub and goes like this

````
{
    "notification":{
        "title":"Notification Hub Test Notification",
        "body":"This is a sample notification delivered by Azure Notification Hubs."
    },
    "data":{
        "property1":"value1",
        "property2":42
    }
}```
````

Comment: why don't you just pass the message value on the App constructor instead of setting the message property and passing a bool?

Comment: idk actually, i wrote the code that way and it works fine when it comes to the `App.xaml.cs` page  when i press the notification while the application on the foreground

Answer (score 0):

When receiving a push notification in the background, the notification data will be passed to the Intent extras in OnCreate as you're already handling. Your Firebase service will only be used when handling messages received while the app is either in the foreground or in the background (not killed).

Verify that the notification payload is using the correct format and that the Intent passed to `MainActivity.OnCreate` has the extras you are expecting.

Comment: i updated and edited and placed my payload format , so that it would help people out

Comment: so how can i edit my `firebaseservices.cs` so that it can handle killed app notfications !

Comment: I don't see any JSON properties in your payload named `message`. It's worth noting that you can't read the `notification` object or its child `title` and `body` values; **only the properties in the `data` object will be passed into the Intent extras.**